# NSPredicate apply predicate on an Object within an object array.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an Array, containing Objects of Order Item Class, and in each order item there is an Article object in it, that contains its details.

Now I want to get the Order items that have a specific name in article of individual order item. How should I write my `NSPredicate`?

What I am trying is something like:

```
   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.itemArticle.articleName CONTAINS[c] '%@'", searchString];
   NSArray *resultsArray = [allOrderItemArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
```

Comment: Try `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"itemArticle.articleName CONTAINS[c] %@", searchString];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removig both the `SELF.` part and the single quotes for the place holder (and close the double quotes).

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"itemArticle.articleName CONTAINS[c] %@", searchString];
NSArray *resultsArray = [allOrderItemArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
```

Comment: working .. Thanks Brother..i wasn't the name but the quotes were creating problems and i want focusing on that.